# Can I use a fingerprint reader to secure access to programs/documents in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, fingerprint

My daughter just got a new HP laptop with a fingerprint reader and Windows 8. She uses the fingerprint reader to log in but would also like to use it for document security.

Is there a way with Windows 8 to secure programs/documents and enable them to be opened via fingerprint?

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to do it with authentec truesuite, but Apple bought the company and shutdown its business. It was the only reliable solution for windows... other products like upek store passwords in clear text!!
Anyway, other solutions aren't viable because authentec had a monopoly, bought also upek before being bought by Applr